# Trying to create an array of object values to be used as options for a dropdown

Tags: reactjs, firebase, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to create an array of objects with key, value, text & image fields, to be used as options for a semantic-ui dropdown component as follows:

```
    const mappedFollowers = followers.map(follower => {
    return {
      key: follower.uid, text: `${follower.firstName} ${follower.lastName}`, value: follower.uid, image: {avatar: true, src:{follower.profileImgUrl ? follower.profileImgUrl : 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png'}}
    }
  })

  const mappedFollowing = following.map(follow => {
    return {
      key: follow.uid, text: `${follow.firstName} ${follow.lastName}` value: follow.uid, image: {avatar: true, src:{follow.profileImgUrl ? follow.profileImgUrl : 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png'}}
    }
  });
```

Upon compilation, I get the error **Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","** on the line :

> const mappedFollowers = followers.map(follower => {
>     678 |     return {
>   679 |       key: follower.uid, text: `${follower.firstName} ${follower.lastName}`, value: follower.uid, image: {avatar: true, src:{follower.profileImgUrl ? follower.profileImgUrl : 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png'}}
>         |                                                                                                                                      ^
>     680 |     }
>     681 |   })

I need help on how I can solve this problem or an alternative solution to what I want to achieve

Comment: The error is exactly informing the problem.

Comment: Stiil shows the same error

Comment: See my answer. You can use a good IDE to help in fixing these problems as the lines with incorrect syntax are marked in red. Anyway, the error you have actually is straight forward.

Comment: Look, @Carl, I know nothing about JS, but just by looking at these two lines you can find the difference where one has a ',' and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
const mappedFollowers = followers.map(follower => {
  return {
    key: follower.uid, text: `${follower.firstName} ${follower.lastName}`, value: follower.uid, image: { avatar: true, src: follower.profileImgUrl ? follower.profileImgUrl : 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png' }
  }
})

const mappedFollowing = following.map(follow => {
  return {
    key: follow.uid, text: `${follow.firstName} ${follow.lastName}`, value: follow.uid, image: { avatar: true, src: follow.profileImgUrl ? follow.profileImgUrl : 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png' }
  }
});
```

The problem is that when you're using ternary expression you don't need to wrap that with `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a comma missing in **mappedFollowing** for value property

```
  const mappedFollowing = following.map(follow => {
    return {
      key: follow.uid, text: `${follow.firstName} ${follow.lastName}`, value: follow.uid, image: {avatar: true, src:{follow.profileImgUrl ? follow.profileImgUrl : 'https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png'}}
    }
  });
```

Comment: Still shows the same error